# How does "round down" work with the Druid's moon circle wild shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

The Player's Handbook states that you can wild shape into a beast with a CR no higher than 1/3 your druid level, rounded down. It says "rounded down," not "truncate," which makes me wonder:

What happens, for example, if the druid's level is 8? 1/3 of 8 is 2,66, so would the maximum CR be 2 or 3?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**For positive numbers, "round down" has the same effect as "truncate."**

You can round the number down to the nearest whole number. Or you can truncate the fractional portion to leave only the integer value. Either way you will end up with the correct maximum CR, which is 2 in this case. Levels and CRs are never negative, so the difference between rounding down and truncating will never come up.

From the PHB, p7 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Round Down**
>   There's one more general rule you need to know at the outset. Whenever you divide a number in the game, round down if you end up with a fraction, *even if the fraction is one-half or greater*.

By contrast, "round up" means to always increase to the nearest whole number when you have a fractional part, no matter how small the fractional part is. Just "rounding", neither up nor down, is slightly trickier; typically this means to round up if the fractional part is 0.5 or greater and round down if it's 0.4999...(repeating) or less.